# Javascript oop dubt

Tags: javascript, oop

I made this two classes below in the code, and I am not sure if I made it in a right oop way. Is it good that I made geometry class and vertex like two distinct classes or maybe they can be one father and child? Another problem is when I call geometry show method and it returns me undefined.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////
// VERTICES
//////////////////////////////////////////


function Vertex(x, y, z) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.z = z;
}


Vertex.prototype.show = function () {
return this.x + ":" + this.y + ":" + this.z;
}


//////////////////////////////////////////
// GEOMETRY
//////////////////////////////////////////


function Geometry() {
this.vertices = [];                   
}


Geometry.prototype.push = function(v) {
this.vertices.push(v);
}


Geometry.prototype.show = function() {
for(var i = 0; i < this.getVertexCount(); i++){
     this.vertices[i].show();// undefined!
   }
}


Geometry.prototype.getVertexCount = function() {
return this.vertices.length;
}




/////TEST/////


function test() {



v = new Vertex(2,4,6);
console.log(v.show());
g = new Geometry();
g.push(v);
console.log(g.show()); //undefined
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm not sure I understand your question: What exactly do you, personally, mean by “the right oop way”? Object orientation is one of many tools, and one with about as many variants as there are programmers, so it helps if you say more precisely what you are looking for – and once your code runs, notice that there is also codereview.stackexchange.com. (Plus, I can't help but ask: Is `vertice` the new spelling of `vertex`?)

Comment: I wanted to ask you if is correct to have inside a class another class like in geometry. It seems to be strict maybe. Sorry for vertex.

Comment: Properties/member variables/attributes/… certainly can and often should refer to/hold/be assigned values of other user-defined types/classes, yes. (If you want to make clarifications to your question, btw, just hit the `edit` button. No need to use comments for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure if I made it in a right oop way.

Seems fine, I can't see any common mistakes.

> My doubt is for geometry class that has a vertice object field inside. Is it correct or the are better way to do it?

Depends on what you need. There's nothing inherently wrong with it, but if you told us your use case we might find a different solution.

> Is it good that I made geometry class and vertex like two distinct classes or maybe they can be one father and child?

No, there should not be any inheritance. There is no [is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) between them. They should be distinct classes, one using the other.

> Another problem is when I call geometry show method and it returns me undefined.

Yes, because it doesn't `return` anything. All those strings that it gets from the invocation of the `Vertice` `show()` calls are thrown away. It seems like you want something like

```
Geometry.prototype.show = function() {
   var result = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < this.getVertexCount(); i++) {
     if (i > 0)
       result += "\n";
     result += this.vertices[i].show();
   }
   return result; // not undefined!
}
```

Comment: Great! My use case is that if you want to create a geometry object , it is made by one or more vertex. Is it good my solution?

Comment: Yes, seems fine to store them in an array then.